# What is the proper syntax for if not defined goto in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a batch script something like this:

```
for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product1" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
    set en=%%a
    set VersionProduct1=!en: =!
    )
GOTO FINDVERSIONS
******Some code in between*******

 :FINDVERSIONS
 sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product2" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql
for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product2" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
    set en=%%a
    set VersionProduct2=!en: =!
    )

sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product3" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql
for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product3" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
    set en=%%a
    set VersionProduct3=!en: =!
    )       

REM construct product paths
SET ProductPath1=.\%VersionProduct1% 
echo %VersionProduct2%
echo %VersionProduct3%
if not defined VersionProduct1 GOTO Product2
SET ProductPath2=.\%VersionProduct2% 
:Product2
echo %ProductPath2%
echo here
SET ProductPath3=.\%VersionProduct2%     
:END
```

The script is doing the following:

It queries the database to get the version of the product installed if the product exists returns the version of it, otherwise, no rows are returned.

If a version number is returned, it is stored in a variable versionProduct which later is used to create the directory variable for the product.

Say product1 is not present in the database and returns no value; hence, versionProduct1 is never defined.
So, I wrote the condition if versionProduct1 is not defined goto product2.
The output after adding the SQL commands outside for loop:

[image]

Output explained:

. - From one of the previous lines in the script not mentioned in the code here.

No output for running the SQL command before for loop 1 in FindVersions block (versionProduct2) as it does not exist

11.0.2 - running the SQL command before for loop 2 in FindVersions block (versionProduct3)

Echo is off - echo %VersionProduct2%

11.0.2 - echo %VersionProduct3%

Comment: Yes, I have that. How would that matter for the error in here? That is disabled to not display every line in the batch file.

Comment: You redirect the output of the `sqlcmd` command into a file, so there is nothing left for the `for` loop to process.

Comment: @Stephan yes, I agree. In that case, I would expect that the variable which is declared inside for loop is never defined and hence, the later condition to check if not defined goto Product2. I added a dummy echo after  :Product2 which is displayed. It is the line after that which gives the syntax error

Comment: There's something odd with with your screenshot. If that is supposed to be the result of running your provided code, where is the topmost line of your image coming from? `echo.` would not print a period, `echo..` or `echo .` may!

Comment: @Compo - A good reason not to use screenshot pictures.

Comment: @Compo I updated my code in the question. This is the actual code. I changed the variable names from what I actually have. The'.' you see on the console is from a line in starting part of the code echo .

Comment: How do you expect your updated code to traverse beyond `:FINDVERSIONS`?

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct now? And what about the image? as that was posted before the code you've now modified multiple times since! Also, as we cannot see your database, can you please post the output from running `sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product2" -i %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql` for a product which exists and another for one which doesn't. This will allow those without a PC, _me_, and those without [tag:sqlplus] to hopefully assist you.

Comment: I do not see delayed expansion enabled in your code.

Comment: @Squashman This is only a part of the script that I have added here in the post. I have delayed expansion enabled at the start of the script.

Comment: @Compo I added the SQL commands and the output you see from them in the post above. the GetVersion.sql file is a simple select query which looks like this:
SET NOCOUNT ON; select VersionName from dbo.syVersionInfo where component=$(product). $(product) comes from the sqlcmd statement in the batch script - Product1, Product2, and Product3 of which Product2 does not exist in the database,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The mistake was using %< >% after the if block instead of !< >!

I changed the script to this-

```
  for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product1" -i 
  %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
      set en=%%a
      set VersionProduct1=!en: =!
  )
  GOTO FINDVERSIONS
  ******Some code in between*******

  :FINDVERSIONS
  sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product2" -i 
  %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql
  for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product2" -i 
  %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
      set en=%%a
      set VersionProduct2=!en: =!
  )

  sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product3" -i 
  %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql
  for /f %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d %DATABASE% -h-1 -v product="Product3" -i 
  %SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetVersionInfo.sql"') do ( 
     set en=%%a
     set VersionProduct3=!en: =!
  )       

  REM construct product paths
  if not defined VersionProduct1 (
        echo Product1 is not installed
        GOTO Product2 
  )
  SET ProductPath1=.\!VersionProduct1!

  :Product2
  if not defined VersionProduct2 (
        echo Product2 is not installed
        GOTO Product3 
  )
  SET ProductPath2=.\!VersionProduct2! 

  :Product3
  if not defined VersionProduct3 (
        echo Product3 is not installed
        GOTO END 
  )
  SET ProductPath3=.\!VersionProduct3!     
 :END
```